# What are prime ideals in $k[[t]]$ and $k((t))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. What are prime ideals in $k[[t]]$ and $k((t))$? I think that $(t-a), a \in k$ and irreducible polynomials in $k[[t]]$ are prime ideals of $k[[t]]$. Are there other prime ideals? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you so sure that $t-a$ with $a \in k^\times$ generates a prime ideal? Do you know that in $k[[t]]$ we have

$$\frac{1}{t-a} = \frac{-1}{a}\frac{t}{1-\frac{a}{t}} = \frac{-1}{a}(1 + (a/t) + (a/t)^2 + \ldots )?$$

There are actually not many prime ideals in $k[[t]]$: The ring of formal power series in one variable over a field is actually a discrete valuation ring! This basically comes two facts. First: Anything with non-zero constant coefficient is invertible. Second: A DVR is a Noetherian local domain of dimension $1$ in which every non-zero, non-unit can be written in the form

$$ut^n, \text{ $n\in\Bbb{Z}$, $u$ a unit}$$

and $t$ the uniformizing parameter. It follows the only prime ideals of $k[[t]]$ are the zero ideal and the ideal generated by $t$. I.e. $\operatorname{Spec} k[[t]]$ consists of two points, the generic point and closed point.
Also, let me add  why it is not a surprise that $\operatorname{Spec} k[[t]]$ consists of only two points. In the following discussion, I will assume $k = \Bbb{C}$.

We would like, theoretically speaking some algebraic object that approximates the ring of holomorphic functions on some analytic neighbourhood $U$ of zero. The polynomial ring in one variable $\Bbb{C}[z]$ is  simply too small, as there are holomorphic functions that are not polynomials like say $\sin z$. So the next algebraic object to consider would be the power series ring. However the problem is now you have allowed arbitrary power series that don't converge, so this is simply too big! In other words we have inclusions

$$k[t] \subseteq \operatorname{Hol}(U,\Bbb{C}) \subseteq k[[t]]$$

and so taking spec we have $\operatorname{Spec} k[[t]] \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} \operatorname{Hol}(U,\Bbb{C}) \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} k[t].$ But now notice that $U$ is an arbitrary neighbourhood about $0$, hence the comment of Alex Youcis that $k[[t]]$ is the ring of functions on a "hyperzoomed" neighbourhood of zero.

Comment: +1 You might want to remark that your statement about power series rings is for when the coefficient ring is a field. Also, you may want to mention that $k((t))$ is a field. And lastly, giving some geometric intuition about $\text{spec }k[[t]]$ being $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ super zoomed in on $0$, and so obviously will have only one point would be a good idea :)

Comment: Nice! I'd mention, if you feel appropriate, that the complex topology zooming is more appropriate a description than the Zariski topology zooming. Namely, if you imitate precisely what you've said you might think that $\text{Spec }\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is the right analogue of your example (since this is what happens when we take the colimit of the functions on increasingly small neighborhoods). But, this is thinking in the wrong topology (the Zariski topology). To get the level of hyperzoom we desire we need to complete $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$

Comment: which corresponds to hyperzooming in the strong (complex) topology (i.e. the right/closer to intuition topology). Don't let me bully you though, it's your answer--and a very good one at that!

Comment: There, for a minute.